# Split these results into array

Tags: php, regex

I'm really struggling to make some regex to turn:

```
Child Non Peak @ $10.75 USD <br/>
<input name="quan0" maxlength="1" size="1" class="star_N"/> <br>
Infant Non Peak @ $13.75 USD <br/>
<input name="quan1" maxlength="1" size="1" class="star_N"/> <br>
Adult Non Peak @ $13.75 USD <br/>
<input name="quan2" maxlength="1" size="1" class="star_N"/> <br>
Senior Non Peak @ $12.50 USD <br/>
<input name="quan3" maxlength="1" size="1" class="star_N"/> <br>
Member Adult Non Peak @ $12.75 USD <br/>
<input name="quan4" maxlength="1" size="1" class="star_N"/> <br>
Member Senior Non Peak @ $11.50 USD <br/>
<input name="quan5" maxlength="1" size="1" class="star_N"/> <br>
Member Child Non Peak @ $9.75 USD <br/>
<input name="quan6" maxlength="1" size="1" class="star_N"/> <br>
```

into an array thats like

```
array (
 value: Child Non Peak @ $10.75 USD 
 price: 10.75
```

Could anyone assist? I have this largely complex piece of regex already but its not fit for purpose.

```
preg_match_all('/class="t12">(?P<type>\w+)[\s@]*(?P<cost>\$[\d.]*)\s+USD(.*)name="(?P<input>quan\w+)"/msU',
               $output,
               $matches,
               PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Comment: Too localised; try rentacoder! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/[\w ]* @ \$?([0-9]{1,}\.?[0-9]*) [A-Z]{2,3} ?/', $output, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

print_r( $matches );
```

gave the next result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Child Non Peak @ $10.75 USD 
            [1] => 10.75
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Infant Non Peak @ $13.75 USD 
            [1] => 13.75
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Adult Non Peak @ $13.75 USD 
            [1] => 13.75
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Senior Non Peak @ $12.50 USD 
            [1] => 12.50
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Member Adult Non Peak @ $12.75 USD 
            [1] => 12.75
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Member Senior Non Peak @ $11.50 USD 
            [1] => 11.50
        )
   [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Member Child Non Peak @ $9.75 USD 
            [1] => 9.75
        )
)
```

Comment: The $ sign in this regexp is optional

Answer (score 1):

`([a-zA-Z ]+ @ \$(\d+\.\d{2}) USD)` should probably give you good results

- `[a-zA-Z ]+` is the product name,
- `@` is between product and the price
- `\$(\d+\.\d{2})` price, `group` captures atleast 1 digit followed by a . followed by 2 digits
- `USD` captures the last space and currency reference

Comment: If you only allow `$` you can exclude all non-dollar currencies, too :).

Answer (score 0):

Use a DOM parser like [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) to inspect the elements.

Using regex to parse HTML may lead to [unintended consequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).